# Wordpress hook for newly published post that can access to post metadata

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, custom-post-type, wordpress-hook

I need to do some **actions only on newly published posts that requires post metadata**.

I've tried many different hooks, but they all also trigger for other "events" like updating post, or if they trigger only on publish, metadata is empty or just has `_edit_lock` value inside.

1. **`auto-draft_to_publish`** hook triggers when I need it, but there is no post meta

```php
add_action(
  'auto-draft_to_publish',
  'wpse120996_specific_post_status_transition'
);

function wpse120996_specific_post_status_transition($post) {
  if ($post->post_type != 'poruke') {
    return;
  }

  $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
  echo "<pre>";
  die(var_dump( $get_post_meta ));
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

2. **`transition_post_status`** works with the right status checks, but there is no post meta as well

```
'publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status
// right time,no post meta
```

3. **`publish_post`** it seems that this one doesn't even trigger for some reason

```php
add_action( 'publish_post', 'myfunction' );
function myfunction($post) {
  echo "<pre>";
  die(var_dump( 'PUBLISHED?' ));
  // this dump is nowhere to be found,
  // I looked in network tab in debugger
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

4. **`save_post`** this one triggers as soon as "Add New" is pressed in a sidebar

I'm having a lot of problem with this and I have hard time believing that something so "basic" would not be a feature in WordPress, but I didn't find anything helpful in my search so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'publish_post'` hook is deprecated, see https://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/publish_post According to the link, `publish_post` only works when something of post-type: post is changed to publish status.
Also, I am surprised `die(var_dump('anything'))` does anything for you, because `var_dump()` doesn't return anything. I would write var_dump('anything'); die(); but this is detail. It seems you have ran into a hard problem, I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the **publish_post** hook, originally It wasnt working because if you have custom post type it has to be used like this:

```
 publish_yourCustomPostName
```

It still didn't have access to post meta from database because it's triggered before postmeta is saved to the database, but luckily I could access post meta from $_POST variable like this:

```
$_POST['acf']
```

Answer (score 1):

First, see my comment below your opening post.

Second, in the 1. example you post, you are dumping `$get_post_meta`, but you meant to dump `$post_meta`.

I noticed `$post` has the post id number in it, not `$post->ID`, so I sent `$post` to `get_post_meta`.

This seemed to work for me:

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'myfunction' );
function myfunction($post) {        
    print_r(get_post_meta($post)); die();
}
```

Be sure to test it while making a new post of type post, not other custom post types or pages, like the link in the comment explained ( https://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/publish_post ) , you need to change the hook to something else to use it on other post types. So 'publish_events' for post type `events`.

**UPDATE**

My apologies, i see the resulting `post_meta` has little info in it:

```
Array ( [_edit_last] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [_encloseme] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) )
```

Maybe it is time to do a feature request to Wordpress (for a post publish hook).

Comment: Thanks for the help, so you Are saying that post publish hook does not exist at all? Damn, I really tought that WordPress would have feature Like that.

Comment: Well, I can't seem to find it, just like you.